# Displaying Excel Worksheet Count

Tags: excel, count, cell, worksheet

Is there a formula to display the number of worksheets in a workbook in a single cell ?

Say I have 3 worksheets and I want to display the page number that the user is on for each page.

I want it to look like this in the footer for the first pagE:

```
Page 1 of 3
```

For the second page:

```
Page 2 of 3
```

And for the third page:

```
Page 3 of 3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your post appears to want footer number in each page (my answer), which is a little different to your first sentence (which Paul has run with). Which is it? :)

Comment: @brettdj: Now that I think about it either should work I need it in 2 locations so both ! haha :)

Comment: You may run into issues if any of your worksheets are too large to fit on a single page. You can use Page Setup to ensure that each worksheet is resized to fit on one page but in some cases this produces an unreadably small result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add in your footers will code like this

1. Press ALt & F11 together to go to the Visual Basic Editor
2. Insert  Module
3. Copy and paste the code below
4. Press ALt & F11 to go back to  excel
5. Run the code

This code will update when you choose to run it. Alternatively you could run the code each time the Workbook Opens using events (which may be overkill), or trap when the user looks to Print, and just add pages numbers to those sheets being printed (rather than the entire workbook)

```
Sub NewHeaders()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sht.PageSetup .CenterFooter = "&P" & " of " & "&N" & " pages"
    Next Sht
End Sub
```

*[Update: put this revised code in the ThisWorkbook module of the file where you want the code to run]*

1. Press ALt & F11 together to go to the Visual Basic Editor
2. Copy and paste the code below inot the 'ThisWorkbook' module
3. Press ALt & F11 to go back to  excel

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
      For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sht.PageSetup .CenterFooter = "&P" & " of " & "&N" & " pages"
       Next Sht
   End Sub
   ```

see picture below
[image]

Comment: How do I `"5. Run the code"`? And yes I would love to have it run whenever the workbook opens using events, how can I do that as well?

Comment: Also is there a way to update it whenever a new worksheet is created?

Comment: Updated as requested. As it will run each time the file opens I think the detection of a new sheet (or deletion of a old sheet) is probably redundant

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly be done easily in VBA

```
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

sheetCount= ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To sheetCount
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("A1").Value = "Page " & i & " of " & sheetCount
Next i
```

Comment: How do I run this whenever that excel file is opened up or a new worksheet is made?

Answer (score 0):

Best option is power shell.

1. Open power shell ISE

   $xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
   $xl.Visible = $true

   ## give right path

   $wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("D:\123.xls") 
   $n = $wb.sheets.count

   Echo $n
   $wb.Close()
   $xl.Quit()

check the output ,Done :):)