# "Page # of #" in a frozen cell

Tags: vba, excel, numbers, cell

I am working on a spreadsheet with a few frozen rows as the top. I need one of the cells to keep track of the page number, and another cell to keep track of the total number of pages.

I've been trying to use [Displaying Excel Worksheet Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681212/displaying-excel-worksheet-count) as a reference, but the best answer there uses headers and footers, but I actually need the numbers to be in my frozen cells.

What I've tried so far:

```
Sub PageNum()
    Dim sheetCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    sheetCount= ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For i = 1 To sheetCount ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("M4").Value = "Page " & i & " of " & sheetCount 
    Next i 
End Sub
```

M4 is the cell that needs the current number.

Update:
This is what I've come up with so far.

```
Sub PageNums()
   Dim WS_Count As Integer
   Dim I As Integer
      WS_Count = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count
      For I = 1 To WS_Count
         ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("M4").Value = I
         Cells(4, 14).Value = WS_Count
      Next I
End Sub
```

Notes: 
-My document is one worksheet with over 1100 lines so far. The first 13 lines are frozen so that they appear on every page when printed. M4 and N4 are in those frozen lines; M4 should display, when printed, the page number (as it would be if I had a header/footer with page numbers, or the same numbers seen when the document is in Page Break Preview) and N4 should display the total number of pages in the document (currently 55 pages).

-The newest code above correctly counts the number of pages in the document and displays that in N4, but it also puts 55 in M4 instead of 1,2,3,... as I want it to. I've tried using the solution posted at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/excel-page-numbering-in-document-not-headers-or/ebfb5b62-b624-4503-a142-6dea1ba813f9 but it doesn't seem to work since M4 is in the frozen rows at the top.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: For a start, trying describing what you have tried to far.

Comment: "Page number" means what exactly? Sheet number?

Comment: @Mark:I've tried combining the 2 answers in the question I liked above, but the use of "ActiveWorksheet" always results in an error.

Comment: The second step you can do is post your code (or formula) in your question. I'm running an open-source Office, but I might give it a try.

Comment: @Tim When printed out, I need the frozen cells to say Page 1 of #, Page 2 of #, etc at the tip of every page. I know this is obvious with a header/footer but I have to use the frozen cells.

Comment: @Mark 
`Sub PageNum()
    Dim sheetCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    sheetCount= ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For i = 1 To sheetCount
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("A1").Value = "Page " &  i & " of " & sheetCount
    Next i
End Sub`

Comment: **put your code in the question, not in the comments**

Comment: Put that into the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable, but it's not clear what you're asking for.

1. Are you trying to get those M4 cells to update on the fly when you add worksheets, or just burn them in once with you subroutine?
2. What is the problem with what you have now?
3. When you say "page" do you mean the page number as printed, or the sequence of the tab name (worksheet name) in the strip at the bottom?

Comment: Please see the update I made in the question. Hopefully they help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was the expected answer...

```
Sub pagenumber()

    Dim VPCount As Integer
    Dim HPCount As Integer
    Dim VPBreak As VPageBreak
    Dim HPBreak As HPageBreak
    Dim NumPage As Integer

    HPCount = 1
    VPCount = 1
    If ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Order = xlDownThenOver Then
        HPCount = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count + 1
    Else
        VPCount = ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count + 1
    End If
    xNumPage = 1
    For Each VPBreak In ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks
        If VPBreak.Location.Column > ActiveCell.Column Then Exit For
        NumPage = NumPage + HPCount
    Next
    For Each HPBreak In ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks
        If HPBreak.Location.Row > ActiveCell.Row Then Exit For
        NumPage = NumPage + VPCount
    Next

    Activesheet.Cells(4, 14) = "Page " & NumPage & " of " & HPCount


End Sub
```